# How to append items to a list called over multiprocess.Process for use outside?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am looking to create a new list with the output from a command run in the get_list function (will return JSON data). It could either be put into one index or into indices like the sublists - I just need to be able to access the information within the list outside of that function. Not sure how I'd be looking to have that information returned or stored outside of the function.

```
def get_list(accountID):
    # call another script here that gets JSON data, 
    # appends to list, and can be accessed globally
    # newList[index][sub-index] or newList[index]

data = subprocess.check_output(['sudo', '/path/to/script.pl', serviceNumber])
data = json.loads(data)

# breaks data into separate lists consisting of no more than 3 objects
sublists = [data[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(data), 3)]
for sublist in sublists:
    for obj in sublist):
        p = Process(target=get_list, args=(obj['account_id'],))
        p.start()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for multiprocessing's `Pool().map`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__=="__main__":
    p = Pool(processes=3)
    newList = p.map(get_list, [obj['account_id'] for obj in data])
```

Have `get_list` return the list:

```
def get_list(accountID):
    # call another script here that gets JSON data
    return result_list
```

Comment: You made it look so simple... Thank you, much appreciated.